# Constructor issue, no suitable constructor found

Tags: java, netbeans

Having some trouble solving this issue. I have been using an example I completed before to assist and it's almost identical and works. The constructors in the addStudents method aren't suitable and i'm unsure exactly what I've done wrong. Have included as much of both the HibernateStudent file and the Student java file as possible. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

```
public HibernateStudent3() {
        Configuration configuration = h2Config(new Class[]{Student.class, Programme.class, Module.class});
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();  
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})

    public void addStudents() {

        System.out.println("Add Students");

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        System.out.println("\n***Session started...");

        System.out.println("\n***Creating student objects...");
        Student s1 = new Student("1", "Bob", "Dylan", "bobdylan@gcu.ac.uk", "ISD");
        Student s2 = new Student("2", "Joni", "Mitchell", "jonimitchell@gcu.ac.uk", "ISD");
        Student s3 = new Student("3", "Paul", "Simon", "paulsimon@gcu.ac.uk", "ISD");       
        System.out.println("\n***Student objects created...");


        System.out.println("\n***Saving student objects...");
        session.save(s1);
        session.save(s2);
        session.save(s3);        
        System.out.println("\n***Student objects saved...");

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.flush();
        session.close();
        System.out.println("\n***Session closed...");  

    }

    public void listStudents() {
        System.out.println("List Students");

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();        
        System.out.println("\n***Session started...");     

        List studentList = session.createQuery("from Student").list();
        System.out.println(studentList.size() + " student(s) found:");
        for (Iterator iter = studentList.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
            Student s = (Student) iter.next();
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.flush();
        session.close();
        System.out.println("\n***Session closed...");         
    }

    public void addProgrammes() {

        System.out.println("Add Programmes");

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        System.out.println("\n***Session started...");

        System.out.println("\n***Creating programme objects...");
        Programme p1 = new Programme("P01627", "Information Systems Development", "FT", null);
        Programme p2 = new Programme("P00280", "IT Management for Business", "FT", null);

        System.out.println("\n***Programme objects created...");

        System.out.println("\n***Module objects retrieved");

        Module m1 = (Module) session.createQuery("from Module where moduleCode = 'M1'").uniqueResult();
        Module m2 = (Module) session.createQuery("from Module where moduleCode = 'M2'").uniqueResult();
        Module m3 = (Module) session.createQuery("from Module where moduleCode = 'M3'").uniqueResult();
        Module m4 = (Module) session.createQuery("from Module where moduleCode = 'M4'").uniqueResult();  
        Module m5 = (Module) session.createQuery("from Module where moduleCode = 'M5'").uniqueResult();
        Module m6 = (Module) session.createQuery("from Module where moduleCode = 'M6'").uniqueResult();
        Module m7 = (Module) session.createQuery("from Module where moduleCode = 'M7'").uniqueResult();

        Set<Module> p1Modules = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6));
        Set<Module> p2Modules = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m7));

        System.out.println("\n***Attach modules to programmes");

        p1.setModules(p1Modules);
        p2.setModules(p2Modules);

        System.out.println("\n***Saving programme objects...");
        session.save(p1);
        session.save(p2);        

        System.out.println("\n***Programme objects saved...");

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.flush();
        session.close();
        System.out.println("\n***Session closed...");        
    }

    public void listProgrammes() {
        System.out.println("List Programmes");

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();        
        System.out.println("\n***Session started...");     

        List programmeList = session.createQuery("from Programme").list();
        System.out.println(programmeList.size() + " programme(s) found:");
        for (Iterator iter = programmeList.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
            Programme p = (Programme) iter.next();
            System.out.println(p);
        }
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.flush();
        session.close();
        System.out.println("\n***Session closed...");         
    }    

    public void addModules() {

        System.out.println("Add Modules");

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        System.out.println("\n***Session started...");

        System.out.println("\n***Creating module objects...");
        Module m1 = new Module("M1", "IT Project Management 2");
        Module m2 = new Module("M2", "Database Systems Development 2");
        Module m3 = new Module("M3", "Research Methods");
        Module m4 = new Module("M4", "Professional Issues");  
        Module m5 = new Module("M5", "Honours Project");
        Module m6 = new Module("M6", "Web Programming 2");
        Module m7 = new Module("M7", "International Business Strategy");        

        System.out.println("\n***Module objects created...");

        System.out.println("\n***Saving module objects...");

        session.save(m1);
        session.save(m2);        
        session.save(m3);  
        session.save(m4);
        session.save(m5);
        session.save(m6);
        session.save(m7);        

        System.out.println("\n***Module objects saved..."); 

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.flush();
        session.close();
        System.out.println("\n***Session closed...");        
    }

    public void listModules() {
        System.out.println("List Modules");

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();        
        System.out.println("\n***Session started...");     

        List moduleList = session.createQuery("from Module").list();
        System.out.println(moduleList.size() + " module (s) found:");
        for (Iterator iter = moduleList.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
            Module m = (Module) iter.next();
            System.out.println(m);
        }
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.flush();
        session.close();
        System.out.println("\n***Session closed...");         
    }      


    public void studentAdmin() {

        // Add Modules
        addModules();

        // List Modules
        listModules();    

        // Add Programmes
        addProgrammes();        

        // List Programmes
        listProgrammes();        

        // Add Students
        addStudents();

        // List Students
        //listStudents();         
    }
```

The Student class.

```
public class Student{

    private long studentId;
    private String matricNo;
    private String firstName;
    private String surname;
    private String email;
    private Programme programme;

    public Student() {
        this.matricNo = null;
        this.firstName = null;
        this.surname = null;
        this.email = null;
        this.programme = null;
    }

    public Student(String matric, String fn, String ln) {
        this.matricNo = matric;
        this.firstName = fn;
        this.surname = ln;
        this.email = null;
        this.programme = null;
    }

    public Student (String matric, String fn, String ln, String e, Programme prg) {        
        this.matricNo = matric;
        this.firstName = fn;
        this.surname = ln;
        this.email = e;
        this.programme = prg;
    }


    public long getStudentId() {
        return this.studentId;
    }

    public void setStudentId(long sid) {
        this.studentId = sid;
    }

    public String getMatricNo() {
        return this.matricNo;
    }

    public void setMatricNo(String matric) {
        this.matricNo = matric;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String fn) {
        this.firstName = fn;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return this.surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String ln) {
        this.surname = ln;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Programme getProgramme() {
        return this.programme;
    }

    public void setProgramme(Programme prog) {
        this.programme = prog;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getMatricNo().hashCode() * 31 + getSurname().hashCode() * 31 +  getFirstName().hashCode() * 31 + getEmail().hashCode() * 31 + getProgramme().hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Student) {
            Student s = (Student)o;
            return  s.getMatricNo() == getMatricNo() &&
                    s.getFirstName().equals(getFirstName()) && 
                    s.getSurname().equals(getSurname()) && 
                    s.getEmail().equals(getEmail()) &&
                    s.getProgramme().equals(getProgramme());
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  "student id: " + getStudentId() + ", " +
                "matric number: " + getMatricNo() + ", " +
                "first name: " + getFirstName() + ", " +
                "surname: " + getSurname() + ", " +
                "email: " + getEmail() + ", " + 
                "programme: " + getProgramme();
    }
```

Comment: What errors are you getting and where?

Answer (score 2):

Problem: You're calling a Student constructor, passing in 5 Strings. i.e.:

```
 new Student("1", "Bob", "Dylan", "bobdylan@gcu.ac.uk", "ISD");
```

If you check the Student class however, you'll see that it in fact has no constructors of this sort, but rather one constructor that takes 3 Strings and one that takes 4 Strings and a Programme object (whatever this is), and so the compiler is correct to complain.

Solution: You can either give the Student class a useful 5 String constructor (but only if this makes sense with your program, something you'll need to decide), or else call one of the constructors that are available, such as the one that takes ***four*** Strings and a Programme reference.

Comment: How on earth is this even downvoted? Common crazy downvoter, find some peace for yourself.

Comment: At least they should offer a better solution.

Comment: Of course. I mean this is ridiculous. I've myself seen this behaviour so many times. Sadly we can do nothing about this.